# Weblogic EJBs: None to display

Tags: deployment, ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c

There is two Weblogic servers with different versions, one is WebLogic Server **12.1.1.0.3 PSU** and the other is **WebLogic Server 12.1.1.0.6 PSU**.

When I install the .ear on the 3 PSU server everything fine, and if I open the deployed instance all the Beans and DAOs are there az the **EJBs** section.

When I install it on the 6 PSU and open deployment it says: **EJBs - None to display** however Modules and Web Services are there.

There is an ejb-jar.xml and weblogic-ejb-jar.xml are present with no ejb definitions, because the beans have annotations like @Stateless, @EJB.

Why the server with the old patch finds the EJBs and the newer dont?

Thanks in advance.